# Debian 9: NVIDIA Card + intel graphics

Tags: gpgpu, debian-stretch

I have a little bit of a dilemma right now:

I have a NVIDIA graphics card and I need to use it for scientific calculations

only (GPU). I have Debian 9 installed on my system and I also have fvwm Window

Manager set up. The thing is I would like to install cinnamon desktop but, for

some reason, after running:

```
apt-get install cinnamon
```

and rebooting, my computer stuck in fallback mode. I think the problem is that

the system doesn't know which card to choose (Nvidia or intel). My goal is to

have cinnamon running on intel and leave the Nvidia card for calculations.

Any idea about how can I make this correctly?

Comment: Is it a notebook with hybrid graphics? If so, no way. You can use graphics or the other, with Nvidia proprietary drivers and by selecting the intended profile at Nvidia X Server Settings (and rebooting).

Comment: No, it is not a notebook.

Comment: In a desktop you need multi-monitor support in the motherboard's firmware (UEFI) in order to use both graphics simultaneously. And if it doesn't have such support then typically the discrete card disables the integrated one. If you have the monitor connected to the Nvidia card then that's the one being used and it most likely requires Nvidia proprietary drivers.